# NSFileManager isWritableFileAtPath false

Tags: objective-c, macos

macApp createFileAtPath fail,Where do I need to change?

same codes

```
NSString * folderPath = @"/Users/shang/Downloads";
NSFileManager *manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager;
NSString *fileAtPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BNRootModel0000.h"];
bool isSuccess = [manager createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:[@"22222" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];

bool isExist = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath];
bool isWritable = [NSFileManager.defaultManager isWritableFileAtPath:fileAtPath];

NSLog(@"__%@_%@_%@", @(isWritable), @(isExist), @(isSuccess));


iphoneApp :
2019-06-21 09:00:25.535204+0800 wer[50978:8502261] __1_1_1

macApp : 
2019-06-21 08:59:58.765259+0800 wwww[50969:8497251] __0_0_0
```

“I expect to work in macApp, but the actual is fail”

Comment: this shouldn't work on iPhone.  In iOS you can't write into  @"/Users/shang/Downloads". I think you have other error.

Comment: macApp's project, Capabilities -> App SandBox -> open by default, close it,work well! hahaha

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. in project, Capabilities -> App SandBox -> File Access，change you need，and work well!